# Does this paradox have a name?

Tags: probability, paradoxes

As a student many years ago I learned of a paradox of something that is almost a certainty, while at the same time being highly improbable.

For example, if you flip 10 coins the chances of all being heads is very slim.  However, if you have an entire Superdome full of people perform the experiment, someone will have an all-heads result.

I thought this paradox has a name but possibly I'm not remembering it correctly or I'm mistaken because I've been googling to no avail...

Comment: The continuous version is even weirder: pick a real number at random between $0$ and $1$. Then the outcome that you get had exactly $0$ chance of coming out, and still you got it.

Comment: Another way to phrase the observation is "the probability of this coincidence is low, but the probability no coincidence at all is also very low".

Comment: This isn't a paradox...

Comment: Let $X$ be the indicator random variable indicating an all-head sequence in ten flips of a fair coin. This is Bernoulli with success probability $1/1024$. If you have $n$ people do the experiment independently, each outcome follows this distribution; the number who get the result is $\sum X_i$. The expected value of this variable is $n/1024$. If $n$ is large (much larger than a thousand), then you'd expect to find at least one person get such a sequence...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to some version of the [Infinite Monkey Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).

Comment: More so because of the close resemblance in the behavior of boisterous fans in a stadium and said monkeys :)

Comment: Note that, for the Infinite Monkey Theorem to apply to this scenario given by the OP, there would either have to be an infinite amount of time in which everyone in the stadium repeatedly flips the coin, or infinitely many people.

If there are finitely many people in a stadium, flipping coins only ten times each, then the IMT does not apply.

Comment: Another possibility is the Birthday Paradox, although this describes an event that becomes very likely with a surprisingly small number of people participating.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick clarification: What you're describing is not actually a paradox--rather it's a property of Probability.

So, for example, if you start flipping a coin over and over for the rest of eternity, the probability that you only get "heads" for each and every flip is infinitely small. However, you *can't* say that this outcome *is impossible*. Instead, the most we can say is that if we start flipping a coin we will **almost surely** get at least one "tails".